# Making predictions with TensorFlow trained model with existing C++ program (not Bazel)

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I have a big C++ program built with Automake and it would be a very big hassle (practically nearly impossible given my time constraints) to convert it to use the Bazel build system. Is there any way I can use a TensorFlow trained model (deep convolutional net) within my program to make predictions (I don't need to do learning within the program right now, but it would be really cool if that can also be done)? Like using TensorFlow as a library?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow has a pretty narrow C API exported in the [c_api.h](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/c/c_api.h) header file. The library file can be produced by building the [libtensorflow.so](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/BUILD#L209) target. The C API has everything you require to load a pre-trained model and run inference on it to make predictions. You *don't* need to convert your build system to Bazel. All you need is to use Bazel to build `//tensorflow:libtensorflow.so` target, and copy the `libtensorflow.so` and `c_api.h` to where you see fit.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try that.

Comment: @kaveman Can I ask another favor? I would really appreciate if you can take a look at this [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40756877/making-predictions-with-tensorflow-trained-model-and-c-api) and help me with it.